# Can I create a single QR code that contains the url, vcard and geo location info?

Tags: url, qr-code, vcf-vcard

Is it possible to create a single QR code that contains the url, vcard and geo location all in one?

Answer (score 1):

QR Codes can contain anything you want, they are just data.

There are no norms for the data inside QR Codes, but there are good practice such as MeCARD, Wireless network, Geolocation. It's hard to predict whether the phone/OS/QR Code reader 
will read it correctly or not.

Here is a great list maintained by ZXing: https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/BarcodeContents.

Anyway, the best is to create a QR Code with a web link, and do your thing in a web page or with a file to download. You can create editable web links for QR Code at http://www.unitag.fr, they are called QR Code Live.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of QR code generators.
Here is one:
http://www.qrstuff.com/

Click on "text" and you can put in all kinds of stuff - up to 1000 characters.

Here is the first line of the Gettysburg Address:
[image]

Comment: So if I'll put Google Maps Location data and web page url to "plain text" generator after scan it will display 2 separate pages? How would i code vcard in plain txt then?? It's all different type of data..

Comment: How about if you give us a specific example. Real numbers/text.

Comment: For example: url: http://ezoczystaenergia.pl localization: Latitude  Longitude
52.22532  21.01490    and data for vcard: Name 
Company 
Title 
Phone number 
Email 
Address 
Address 2

Comment: I just did it, and it worked fine. All the information was stored and I could retrieve it with my smartphone from the screen of my computer

Comment: Sounds great, thank you. But did the map displayed to you and you had a posibility to add contact to phone by vcard??

Comment: There is no "map" displayed, just the coordinates. You'd have to write code the read the Qr, then look up a map and then display it. Now I see what you're asking for, and it is VERY complex.

Answer (score 0):

One QR code generator is also at [zxing QR code generator](http://zxing.appspot.com/generator). I used it and generated a QR code and scanned that code with QR code reader app on my Windows 8 phone. Works great. Many thanks to those guys at zxing. Moreover, you can generate QR code in any app (Windows Phone/Android/iPhone/WinForms/Windows 8 desktop app) using the libraries for respective platform.

An example in .NET 4.0 follows. This code doesn't use any obsolete classes/methods.

```
        string contact = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\****\Documents\****.vcf");

        BarcodeWriter bcWriter = new BarcodeWriter();
        ZXing.Rendering.BitmapRenderer renderer = new ZXing.Rendering.BitmapRenderer();

        bcWriter.Renderer = renderer;
        bcWriter.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
        Bitmap bm = bcWriter.Write(contact);

        pictureBoxQrCode.Image = bm;
        bm.Save(@"C:\Users\****\Documents\****.png");
```